# In Tensorflow, can I use tf.gather() for partial connection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to implement partial connection between layers. Let say, I want to use only some of feature maps, e.g., first and third one.

- Is it correct to use tf.gather() for this purpose?
- Can I just use indexing operator [ ] instead of tf.gather() as below?
- Will gathering indices work in terms of back propagation?  It is hard for me to imagine how Tensorflow will *know* internally the connection was from the first and third (which info is hard-coded) in the internal back-prop process. Does the function tf.gather remember the connection?

code:

```
# let say, L1 is layer1 output of shape [batch_size x image_size x image_size x depth1]
partL1 = L1[:, :, :, [0,2]]
# W2 is a tf variable of shape [5, 5, 2, depth2]
conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(partL1, W2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, no, yes. :-)
(a)  Yes, you can use gather to pick a subset of a layer to propagate to the next layer, as you suggested.

(b)  No, you can't use the indexing operator, unfortunately.  You need to explicitly invoke `tf.gather()`.

(c)  Yes, TensorFlow will stash a copy of the indices used for gathering and save them for backprop.  You can see [the implementation of Gather's Gradient](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/array_grad.py#L199) if you're curious about how - it looks at the inputs to the op and propagates back using those.